# Javascript Toggle : Hide div on click of anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs. When I click on **3 dots** , then the div is appearing and on clicking the same **3 dots** , same div is disappearing. But I want to hide the div, even if I click anywhere in the document.

There are two circles. When I click on one circle, then a div is shown and when I click on another circle, then the opened div is closing and related div is opening but when I click anywhere on the document, then none of the div are closing.

```js
$("#discussion_declined , #discussion_pending").click(function() {
  var relatedDiv = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.discussion_edit_div');
  relatedDiv.toggle("fast");
  $('.discussion_edit_div').not(relatedDiv).hide('fast');

});
```

```css
.discussion_small_round_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: #2d3446;
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 15px;
  float: right;
}
.discussion_small_round_div:after {
  content: '\2807';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 1px;
}
.discussion_edit_div {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  border: thin #ced0d1 solid;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
ul li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #838383;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #eeeded;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel discussion_panel_div no_background no_box_shadow" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="panel-heading no_border_radius bg-dark set_padding_0">
    <div class="discussion_small_round_div pull-right cursor_pointer" id="discussion_declined"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="discussion_edit_div">
    <ul>
      <li> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp; Replicate</li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp; Delete</li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp; Deactivate</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="panel discussion_panel_div no_background no_box_shadow" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="panel-heading no_border_radius bg-dark set_padding_0">
    <div class="discussion_small_round_div pull-right cursor_pointer" id="discussion_pending"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="discussion_edit_div">
    <ul>
      <li> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp; Replicate</li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp; Delete</li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp; Deactivate</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried using that but when i again click on 3 dots div then again div is appearing instead of closing

Comment: Check my answer mate...

Comment: @mplungjan Checked the OP's requirement and the dupe. This is not the exact dupe or the dupe doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praveen's answer is nice but you can also achieve the same without tweaking your HTML.

Just add this to your jQuery:

```
$(window).click(function() {
//Hide the menus if visible
$('.discussion_edit_div').hide('fast');
});

$("#discussion_declined , #discussion_pending").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var relatedDiv = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.discussion_edit_div');
  relatedDiv.toggle("fast");
  $('.discussion_edit_div').not(relatedDiv).hide('fast');

});
```

And your are good to go.

This achieves one more thing which is that once you have opened one ul, then you can directly toggle to another ul by clicking once. In Praveen's answer you have to click twice in order to open the other ul.

Check the link:https://jsfiddle.net/zfqqqr1c/1/

Answer (score 0):

How Bootstrap handles this is interesting. They have a mask, and the only thing you can click is the mask or the items in the menu.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".mask").hide();
  $("nav > ul > li > a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("open");
    $(".mask").show();
    return false;
  });
  $(".mask").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".open").removeClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; line-height: 1; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
a {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}

.mask {position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 8;}

nav > ul > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 30%;}
nav > ul > li a {display: block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
nav > ul ul {position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 9; display: none;}
nav > ul > li.open > ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div class="mask"></div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. i just want to close div on clicking anywhere to the document. I am not getting your code. can't you do in my code?

Comment: @Rishi Yes, possible. I'll do it now.

Comment: @Rishi Glad it helped you. Code ref: http://jsbin.com/dopuyujiwe/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Rishi Er... Why did you change the accepted answer?

Comment: I found the 2nd one more efficient than the one that you have answered. that's why..

Comment: @Rishi Sure... :)

Comment: in your answer , I had to click twice to open div.

Comment: @Rishi Sure... You can do in a different way. Yea, the other answer is good. :D